# Prove that given 17 integers, the sum of 9 of them is divisible by 9.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that given any $17$ integers, there exist nine of them whose sum is divisible by $9.$

I'm pretty sure we have to use the pigeonhole principle, with the possible remainders as the pigeonhole, but that gives a lot of possibilities and I don't know where to start.

I tried to compare it to this question which was easier to solve:

Prove that given any $5$ integers, there exist three of them whose sum is divisible by $3.$

Comment: How'd you do the simpler version.  I imagine this is probably exactly the same.  In both cases you have $2n -1$ integers and need to prove htat there are $n$ of them whose sum is divisible by $n$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy–Davenport_theorem the theorem is called Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem though I can't find the proof

Comment: @kingW3 Note the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388379/602049) of my proposed duplicate indicates it's always true for $2n - 1$, i..e, for $n = 9$, it's true for $2n - 1 = 17$, and for $n = 3$ it's true for $2n - 1 = 5$. Also, the answer's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388310/show-that-in-any-set-of-2n-integers-there-is-a-subset-of-n-integers-whose-s#comment6971015_3388379) gives a link to original paper with the theorem you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, but the answer on the original is not easy and refers to the Chevary-Warning theorem without proof.  Don't know if this is easier with a specific $n=9$.

Comment: @fleablood With a proof for the simpler case the OP asks about, i.e., for $5$ integers having at least $3$ with a sum of $3$, you can prove it for your case of $17$ integers having a subset of $9$ being a multiple of $9$ using the second page of the [original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2860/2b7734c115bbab7141a1942a2c974057ddc0.pdf) of the proof where it shows how to fairly easily extend the result to the product of any $2$ values, in particular $3$ and $3$ here. This is after it proves it for all primes, so it can then prove the case for all $n$.

Comment: @LilyPotter You can use the results from [Prove that for any set of 5 integers, there is at least one subset of 3 integers whose sum is divisible by 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998977/prove-that-for-any-set-of-5-integers-there-is-at-least-one-subset-of-3-integers?rq=1) to prove your simpler case of $n = 3$ values summing to a multiple of $3$ among $2n - 1 = 5$ integers, then use what I suggest in my comment above to then prove it for $n = 9 = 3 \times 3$.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate.  The general  $2n$ and $n$ theorem is much more difficult than the specific case in this problem. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @awkward I agree it's not the best, but I just found [Pigeon - Hole principle and remainder modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112979/pigeon-hole-principle-and-remainder-modulus), that actually asks the same question, &  with your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2117219/602049) basically explaining what I suggest in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462056/prove-that-given-17-integers-the-sum-of-9-of-them-is-divisible-by-9#comment7117249_3462056) above. Thus, I'm also voting to reopen & then will vote to close as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ha Ha! I had forgotten that I answered that question!  Thanks for reminding me.